# PrimeFaces - JSF tree's context menu can't show

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Now I want to use JSF tree's mouse right menu, which is just like the link's example. When I click the mouse right, the menu can be show and disappear immediately. I don't know how to show the mouse right key menu (treecontext). Can you give some advice about that? Thanks.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeContextMenu.jsf

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"       
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"       
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"       
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"       
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="treeform">  


    <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="tree" rendered="true"  dynamic="true" cache="false" selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">       
        <p:ajax event="expand"    listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}"/>  
        <p:ajax event="collapse"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeCollapse}" />
        <p:ajax event="select"    listener="#{tableBean.showScenario}"  update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable :mainForm:dynaFormGroup :mainForm:breadcrumbmenu :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:treecontext" />         
        <p:ajax event="unselect"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeUnselect}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable :mainForm:dynaFormGroup :mainForm:breadcrumbmenu :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:treecontext" /> 
        <p:treeNode id="treeNode" rendered="true" animate="true"  expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
            <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" id="lblNode"/>  
        </p:treeNode>  
    </p:tree>    

    <p:contextMenu id="treecontext" for="tree" rendered="true"  >          
        <p:menuitem value="Add Product"    disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel==1?false:true}" icon="ui-icon-contact" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createproductdlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createproductdlg').show()" />
        <p:menuitem value="Add Capability" disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel==2?false:true}" icon="ui-icon-contact" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createcapabilitydlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createcapabilitydlg').show()" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Add Feature"    disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel>=3?false:true}" icon="ui-icon-contact" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createfeaturedlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createfeaturedlg').show()" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Add Scenario"   disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel>=3?false:true}" icon="ui-icon-contact" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('scenariodlg').show()"  onclick="PF('scenariodlg').show()" /> 
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="tree" actionListener="#{treeBean.create}" icon="ui-icon-close"/>  
    </p:contextMenu>
   </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

some part of main page code

```
<h:form id="mainForm">

<p:layout id="fulllayout" fullPage="true">  
<!-- top menu start -->
<p:layoutUnit id="layoutunittop" position="north" size="50">
    <p:breadCrumb id="breadcrumbmenu" rendered="true">  
     <p:menuitem value="Categories" url="#"  />  
     <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" disabled="true" />   
     <p:menuitem value="Add Product"    disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel==1?false:true}" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createproductdlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createproductdlg').show()" />
     <p:menuitem value="Add Capability" disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel==2?false:true}" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createcapabilitydlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createcapabilitydlg').show()" />  
     <p:menuitem value="Add Feature"    disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel>=3?false:true}" action="#{treeBean.setDialogTitle}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('createfeaturedlg').show()"    onclick="PF('createfeaturedlg').show()" />  
     <p:menuitem value="Add Scenario"   disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel>=3?false:true}" update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable  :mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:tree " oncomplete="PF('scenariodlg').show()"  onclick="PF('scenariodlg').show()" /> 
    </p:breadCrumb>
</p:layoutUnit>
<!-- top menu end -->

 <!-- menu begin -->
 <p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitleft" position="west" size="360"  resizable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" minSize="260">
    <p:accordionPanel id="accordingpanel1" rendered="true" >                         
     <p:tab id="accordingpanel1tab" title="Project">      
       <ui:include src="tree.xhtml" /> 
     </p:tab>                          
     <p:tab title="Test Set">                             
       <h:outputText value="Test Set" />                         
     </p:tab>                          
     <p:tab title="Report">                             
      <!--   <h:outputText value="Report" />  -->
      <!--   <p:calendar mode="inline" navigator="none"/> -->                        
     </p:tab>                     
     </p:accordionPanel>                 
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <!-- menu end -->
....
```

Comment: When I remove ":mainForm:accordingpanel1:treeform:treecontext", I can see the mouse right menu. But I can't get the value of "disabled="#{tableBean.selectedProjectNodeLevel==1?false:true}". I think the disapear reason is due to update. But I need update to get the latest value. After that, I can operate on the menu according the latest value(disable or enable). Can someone give one solution to solve this? Keep the menu update and show the mouse right menu. Thanks.

Comment: When I move the mouse to the left of menu arrow, the menu don't disappear. I think it should be one bug of primefaces. If you have solution to fix the bug, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: which version of primefaces are you using?